# Why using Task to load multiple pages' content length gives me the same result?

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, task

I am trying to get the content length of multiple pages using Task in .NET Core asynchronously:

```cs
public static async Task GetContentLengthAsync(string url)
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    var page = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(page.Length);
}
```

If I use it like this to take the first 100 pages' content length:

```cs
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    Task.Run(() => GetContentLengthAsync($"https://www.website.com/view/{i}"));
}
```

=> all the outputs are the same or different but incorrect. (but I get the results very fast)

If I run the Task with await like this by just calling the `GetLengthsAsync()`:

```cs
public static async void GetLengthsAsync()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {

        await Task.Run(() => GetContentLengthAsync($"https://www.website.com/view/{i}"));
    }
}
```

=> the output is correct and I can still type in the console and do other tasks in that time but each of the `GetContentLengthAsync` tasks waits the other to be completed and uses only one thread at a time. Is there a way to make it run not only asynchronously but also on multiple threads at the same time without losing information?

P.S. I want to use Tasks because it's an university project and I know that there probably are better ways of doing it(but those are the requirements). It's more of a problem solving task to better understand how Task works.

Comment: As a side note, the `HttpClient` class is intended to be instantiated [once](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#create-and-initialize-httpclient), and reused throughout the life of an application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lambda function in a for() loop will ['capture' the loop variable](https://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/). Most requests would have been for /view/100.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
   int localCopy = i;
   Task.Run(() => GetContentLengthAsync($"https://www.website.com/view/{localCopy}"));
}
```